# Determinants in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, determinants, matrix-theory

In graph theory, we work with adjacency matrices which define the connections between the vertices. These matrices have various linear-algebraic properties. For example, their trace can be calculated (it is zero in the case of a *loopless* graph, i.e., an irreflexive symmetric binary relation). And we can also calculate their determinants.

*How would you interpret the determinant in the context of a graph?*
For example, I teach network theory and the calculation of 'eigenvector centrality' requires the use of determinants. But the general question always comes up: what does the determinant mean in the context of the network (or graph)? Does it tell me of a property of the network that is useful?

In essence, I am trying to find a user-friendly interpretation of determinants in the context of networks or graphs.
I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: This is not quite what you are asking, but the determinant of the graph Laplacian counts the number of spanning trees.  This is known as Kirchhoff's matrix tree theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_theorem

Comment: You may be interested in Frank Harary, The determinant of the adjacency matrix of a graph, SIAM Review, Vol. 4, No. 3. (Jul., 1962), pp. 202-210, which I found at http://www.yaroslavvb.com/papers/harary-determinant.pdf   If you have access to Math Reviews online, you might look for papers which cite this one.

Comment: @JeffSchenker The determinant of the graph Laplacian is actually 0.

Comment: @JeffSchenker As Jernej has pointed out, not the Laplacian itself, but any order $n-1$ principal sumbatrix thereof.

Comment: @Feliz and Jernej, thanks for pointing this out.  you are of course correct.

Comment: I won't make this an answer since arguably this is not a property **of the an adjacency** matrix (rather of a pair consisting of a graph and a Pfaffian orientation, i.e., there is additional data involved), yet since the OP explicitly allowed "networks" (which are usually taken to subsume directed graphs), it is on-topic to mention: if you can give your graph a **Pfaffian orientation**, then the determinant of the corresponding **signed** adjacency matrix equals the [*square of the total number of perfect matchings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FKT_algorithm).

Answer (score 28):

Let $G$ be a graph with adjacency matrix $A$. Let $s(G)$ be the number of connected components of $G$ that are cycles and $r(G)$ the number of connected components that are either $K_2$ or even cycles. Then $$\det(A) = \sum_{H} (-1)^{r(H)} 2^{s(H)}$$ where the sum is over all spanning subgraphs $H$ of $G$ that have only $K_2$ and cycles as their connected components.

In particular if $T$ is a tree the determinant of its adjacency matrix is $\pm$ the number of perfect matchings of $T$.

A relevant passage from N. Biggs: *Algebraic Graph Theory*. Second Edition. Cambridge University Press, is:

[image: excerpt from Biggs: Algebraic Graph Theory]

This identity can be generalized to all other coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A.$ For more information check the chapter "Determinant expansions" of Biggs' book on algebraic graph theory.

Comment: Looking at Biggs (chapter "Determinant expansions"), and also the original Harary 1962 paper referenced there, it seems that $r(H)$ represents the number of even components, not the number of $K_2$ components as you describe here. Is that correct?

Comment: @TylerStreeter That's right r(H) has a different meaning in general (the rank of H). In this case the function is simplified since we only evaluate it for the specific class of graphs

Comment: Even in this specific class of graphs (i.e. spanning subgraphs of $G$ having only $K_2$ and cycles as components), I think $r(H)$ here should be (congruent to, mod 2) the number of even components, not the number of $K_2$ components. Or am I missing something?

Comment: To rephrase my comments: in both the Biggs and Harary references, it appears that the expression involves $(-1)$ raised to the power "number of even components," not "number of $K_2$ components." So the description above appears incorrect, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @TylerStreeter Yes, you're right about the references. I am not sure at this point how I got to the presented definition of $r(H)$ and at this point its safer to just edit the post to use the number of even cycles.

Comment: I'll think about special cases where all even components are $K_2$. In any case, thanks for the quick responses, and for posting this helpful answer in the first place.

Answer (score 13):

If your graph is directed and each edge has weight $1$ then the determinant counts the number of not-necessarily-connected-cycles (that is subgraphs being disjoint unions of connected cycles) passing through every vertex of the graph. The cycle is counted as $-1$ if the number of its components has different parity than the number of vertices of the graph, otherwise it is counted as $1$.