# Properties of graphs with Hankel-like adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, sparse-matrices, hankel-matrices

I am having undirected graphs with adjacency matrices which have a regular Hankel-like form, e.g.,
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & (6\times 0 \text{ then } 1) \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & (5 \times 0 \text{ then } 1)\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots\\
\vdots
\end{pmatrix}$$

In other words, a sequence "0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, $\dots$", where $1$s are at positions 3, 8, 15, 24, 35, etc. ($n^2-1, n\in \mathbb{N}$).

Since I could not find anything about these types of graphs, I would like to know if they have a name (afaik there exist Toeplitz graphs), or if there is something known about their properties. The motivation for this problem comes from the question posted here: [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199677/arranging-numbers-from-1-to-n-such-that-the-sum-of-every-two-adjacent-number)

Some minor ("brute-force") observations and known information:

1. For the size $N<14$ the graph is disconnected.
2. At least for the size $N<25$ the graph is planar.
3. For $N=15, 16, 17, 23$ and probably for all $N>24$, the graph contains a Hamiltonian path (conjecture).
4. First Hamiltonian cycle is probably for $N=32$.

Obviously the graph is quite sparse, so Dirac's, Ore's, Chvatal's theorem for Hamiltonicity cannot be applied here (I have a feeling that it remains very sparse also as $N\to\infty$, since $n$ grows faster than $N$ and thus also the zeros fill up the adjacency matrix more and more).

Since the matrix is quite regular, I was wondering if some approach using the relation between the determinant of the matrix and spanning subgraphs (e.g. [Determinants in Graph Theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134956/determinants-in-graph-theory)) cannot be applied here. But I was unable to come up with something reasonable so far. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Additionally $trace{A}=\sum\lambda_i = \lfloor{\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}}\rfloor$.