# Interpreting positive semidefinite matrix as a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices, matrix-theory, semidefinite-programming

> Given any symmetric matrix $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, if $S \succeq 0$, is there a way to encode $S$ into a graph such that it takes into account the positive semidefinite constraint, and ideally, also the sparsity of $S$?

For any symmetric matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, I think we can encode it as an undirected graph by simply considering $n$ vertices, and with entries of the matrix corresponding to edge weights. However, I cannot think of any specific ways to characterize the subset of positive semidefinite matrices. Maybe we can use the determinant characterization to do some tricks, but I am not very familiar with graph theory.

The motivation is that I want to consider the minimization problem $\operatorname{min}_{X \succeq 0} \|\mathscr{A}(X) - b\|^{2}$, where $\mathscr{A}(X) = [\langle A_{1},X \rangle, \langle A_{2}, X\rangle ,\dots ,\langle A_{n}, X \rangle]$. $A_{1},\dots ,A_{n} \in \{ 0,1 \}^{n \times n}$ and are pairwise orthogonal, somewhat like a generalization of matrix completion. I just recently heard of Chordal graphs, and maybe it's related, but I certainly need to read more about it.

Comment: You may find Ch. 9 of this reference helpful: https://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/publications/chordalsdp.pdf

Comment: You might want to look into the work of Miroslav Fiedler, espacially chapter 6.1 and 6.2 of his book "Matrices and Graphs in Geometry" where he assigns to graphs the Laplacian (a positive semidefinite matrix) and conversely to a simplex given by a positive definite matrix he asssigns a graph.

Comment: If you replace a solution $X$ with $\Phi(X)$ where $\Phi$ is the projection onto the coherent algebra generated by $A_1, \ldots, A_n$, then $\mathcal{A}(X)$ does not change and $\Phi$ also preserves positivity. So you can restrict your search to matrices in the coherent algebra generated by $A_1, \ldots, A_n$. If this happens to be an association scheme, then the positivity condition can be replaced by linear constraints.

Answer (score 0):

One characterization of semidefinite positive matrices among symetric matrices is that all their principal minors are positive.

The determinant of the adjacency matrix of a graph has a graph-theoritic interpretation (see the post [Determinants in Graph Theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134956/determinants-in-graph-theory)).

Paraphrasing @Jernej in the post aforementionned:

"Let $G$ be the graph with adjacency matrix $M$, $s(G)$ be the number of connected components of $G$ that are cycles and $r(G)$ the number of connected components that are either $K_2$ or even cycles then $\operatorname{det}(M)=\sum_{H}{(-1)^{r(h)}2^{s(H)}}$

Where the sum ranges on the subgraph $H$ that only have $K_2$ and cycles as connected components."

One can interpret the $k^{th}$ principal minor as $(-1)^k$ times the determinant of the adjacency matrix of the subgraph given by taking the $k$ first vertices of $G$.

By setting $\mathcal{H}$ the set of $H$ subgraph of $G$ that only have $K_2$ and cycles as connected components and partitioning it as $\mathcal{H}_k$ the set of $H$ subgraph of $G$ that only have $K_2$ and cycles as connected components containing $v_k$ and not containing $v_j$ for $j>k$.

The condition then becomes a condition on the $\mathcal{H}_k$.

For the application you want, if I understand well all matrices have coeficient $0$ or $1$ (ie the graph is unweighted) then, quoting @Adam Przeździecki in the above post:

"If your graph is directed and each edge has weight $1$ the determinant counts the number of not-necessarily-connected-cycles (that is subgraphs being disjoint unions of connected cycles) passing through every vertex of the graph. The cycle is counted as −1 if the number of its components has different parity than the number of vertices of the graph, otherwise it is counted as 1."

Which makes the computation much more graph-theoritic-like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm a little confused. $X$ is my case is just some positive semidefinite matrix. and it's the linear transformation $A_i$ that has a coefficient of 0 or 1. I'm trying to interpret X, which entries can be any number in $\mathbb{R}$, so I'm not sure if this immediately applies to this case, but it might work with some tweaking, though the final conclusion you quoted no longer applies